# Json array passing through Larvel Vue but not working as intended

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am using laravel backend for vuejs, after passing the values using json

```
return response()-> json(
  array('product' => $product,
  product_materials' =>$product_materials)
);
```

for `/product_details/1` i am getting product:{}, product_materials: [{}] which is what I want
but `/product_details/2` etc it is sending values product:{}, product_materials:{"number":{}}
what is the issue here? because of this I cannot do dynamic calculation.

`/product_details/1`

```
{
    "product": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Wooden Table",
        "description": "Dining",
        "quantity": 2,
        "material_items": 7,
        "material_cost": 87.6,
        "waste_percentage": 5,
        "waste_amount": 4.38,
        "labour_percentage": 15,
        "labour_amount": 13.796999999999999,
        "equipment_cost": "10.000",
        "other_percentage": 8,
        "other_amount": 9.26216,
        "margin_percentage": 10,
        "margin_amount": 12.503915999999998,
        "sub_total": 137.54307599999999,
        "amount": 275.08615199999997,
        "created_at": "2022-04-04T20:02:16.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-04-09T13:04:44.000000Z",
        "created_by": 1,
        "updated_by": 1,
        "deleted_by": null,
        "deleted": 0
    },
    "product_materials": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "product_id": 1,
            "description": "MDF Sheet",
            "quantity": 10,
            "rate": "5.000",
            "amount": "50.000",
            "delete": 0,
            "created_at": "2022-04-04T20:03:13.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-04-04T20:03:13.000000Z",
            "created_by": 1,
            "updated_by": null,
            "deleted_by": null
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "product_id": 1,
            "description": "Filer",
            "quantity": 2,
            "rate": "10.000",
            "amount": "20.000",
            "delete": 0,
            "created_at": "2022-04-04T20:03:53.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-04-04T20:03:53.000000Z",
            "created_by": 1,
            "updated_by": null,
            "deleted_by": null
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "product_id": 1,
            "description": "Primer",
            "quantity": 1,
            "rate": "4.000",
            "amount": "4.000",
            "delete": 0,
            "created_at": "2022-04-04T20:04:15.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-04-04T20:04:15.000000Z",
            "created_by": 1,
            "updated_by": null,
            "deleted_by": null
        },
    ]
}
```

and for other example: `/product_details/2`

```
    "product": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Table",
        "description": "1.5m",
        "quantity": 1,
        "material_items": 1,
        "material_cost": 50,
        "waste_percentage": 2,
        "waste_amount": 1,
        "labour_percentage": 2,
        "labour_amount": 1.02,
        "equipment_cost": "20.000",
        "other_percentage": 2,
        "other_amount": 1.4404,
        "margin_percentage": 2,
        "margin_amount": 1.4692079999999998,
        "sub_total": 74.929608,
        "amount": 74.929608,
        "created_at": "2022-04-07T13:15:20.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-04-09T13:21:54.000000Z",
        "created_by": 1,
        "updated_by": 1,
        "deleted_by": null,
        "deleted": 0
    },
    "product_materials": {
        "11": {
            "id": 12,
            "product_id": 2,
            "description": "Wood",
            "quantity": 10,
            "rate": "5.000",
            "amount": "50.000",
            "delete": 0,
            "created_at": "2022-04-09T10:27:21.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-04-09T10:27:21.000000Z",
            "created_by": 1,
            "updated_by": null,
            "deleted_by": null
        }
    }
}
```

```
$product_materials = product_materials::all()->where('product_id', $product->id);
```

getting the product materials based on product's id.

```
$product = product::find($id);
```

and in Vue.js

```
data() {     return { product: {}, product_materials: [{}] };   },
```

Comment: because you manipulated the collection and preserved the indexes on it. it would help us help  you if you posted the source of those collections you are returning. how are you setting `$product_materials`

Comment: @N69S `$product_materials = product_materials::all()->where('product_id', $product->id);` getting the product materials based on product's id. 
 `$product = product::find($id);` and in Vue.js 
  `data() {
    return { product: {}, product_materials: [{}] };
  },`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel API - Vue js axios to display from Json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71797838/laravel-api-vue-js-axios-to-display-from-json)

Comment: @RohìtJíndal It partially did, as I mentioned only `/product_details/1` is getting the right result. `/product_details/2` and so on are not.. hence I asked this question here

Comment: @Faizan `/product_details/1` is giving you the right format by "coincidence" since the first elements in the collection `product_materials::all()` do belong to `product_id = 1` (the indexes are sequential in the result). add another product_materials belonging to `product_id = 1` in your table (higher id) and it will return the indexes like the results with `/product_details/2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are filtering the collection with `where()` after you get all the product_materials from the DataBase.

Change it to this and it will solve your issue. aka apply the condition before getting the results from database (way better performance too)

```
$product_materials = product_materials::where('product_id', $product->id)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

this is not related to vuejs, try to return the product_materials as array of objects even for one object

it should be like this

```
"product_materials": [
    {
        "id": 12,
        "product_id": 2,
        "description": "Wood",
        "quantity": 10,
        "rate": "5.000",
        "amount": "50.000",
        "delete": 0,
        "created_at": "2022-04-09T10:27:21.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-04-09T10:27:21.000000Z",
        "created_by": 1,
        "updated_by": null,
        "deleted_by": null
    }
]
```

Comment: I used `$product_materials = product_materials::all()->where('product_id', $product->id);` in the controller. Laravel makes all() as array right? I even used toArray(), I am getting the same result. The first one is array but the 2nd, 3rd, 4th etc are not.. they show as "product_materials":{"number"{}}

Comment: can you try this `product_materials::where('product_id', $product->id)->get();`

Answer (score 0):

use :

```
$product_materials = product_materials::query()
    ->where('product_id', $product->id)
    ->get();
```

OR :

```
$product_materials = product_materials::query()
    ->where('product_id', $product->id)
    ->first()();
```